# Is this object garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

I have 2 modules:

```
//a.js
var obj = {};
require ("./b")(obj);
obj = null;
//POINT P

//b.js
module.exports = function (obj){
  obj = null
};
```

At the point P, will obj be a candidate to be garbage collected?

Edit: Ok, it seems that Node.js just caches the module "metadata" (search `function NativeModule` [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js)), so yes, obj will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `obj` in your first module is totally different from the `obj` in your second module, which is just a parameter. The fact that you use the name '`obj`' twice doesn't make any difference.

Comment: If module b doesn't null the `obj` argument, then the object is not garbage collected because you have `obj` pointing to it, but in this case `obj` is nulled. The real question is, does node.js caches in some way the exported function/parameters?

Comment: The `obj` in module b has nothing to do with the `obj` in module a. In module b, `obj` is just a parameter, which you can give any name, and in the context of that function, `obj` just means the parameter and the other `obj` is not visible.